# Remove duplicate dictionaries from 2d list in python

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

I have a 2D list of of dictionaries:

```
results = [
    [{'a':1, 'b':[1,2,3]},
     {'a':10, 'b':[7,8,9]},
     {'a':100, 'b':[100,200,300]}], 
    [{'a':123, 'b':[9,5,2]},
        {'a':100, 'b':[100,200,300]}], 
    [{'a':10, 'b':[7,8,9]}]
]
```

I want to flatten this 2D list into a 1D list and then remove duplicate dictionaries. By removing duplicates I mean for example remove multiple entries of same dictionary like `{'a':100, 'b':[100,200,300]}` in the first and second list. currently I am using the following technique

```
from itertools import chain
x = list(chain.from_iterable(results)) # Flattens the list of dicts
y = [dict(t) for t in set([tuple(d.items()) for d in x])]
```

But the last time throws the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/myapp/main.py", line 122, in <module>
    y = [dict(t) for t in set([tuple(d.items()) for d in x])]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The expected output would be a single list of unique dicts like the following

```
[
    {'a':1, 'b':[1,2,3]},
     {'a':10, 'b':[7,8,9]},
     {'a':100, 'b':[100,200,300]}, 
    {'a':123, 'b':[9,5,2]},
]
```

Can someone guide me if this is a right approach or not. If not then what would be the better and correct approach ? Thanks

Comment: You can flat the list of dict by `[i for d in results for i in d]`. For deduplication you didn't specify the criteria.

Comment: @GarbageCollector please see the edit

Comment: Can you please gives us expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a very simple way:

```
set_results = []
for r in results:
    for sub_r in r:
        if not sub_r in set_results:
            set_results.append(sub_r)
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': [1, 2, 3]},
 {'a': 10, 'b': [7, 8, 9]},
 {'a': 100, 'b': [100, 200, 300]},
 {'a': 123, 'b': [9, 5, 2]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make flat list like this:

```
in_list = [
   [
    {'a':1, 'b':[1,2,3]},
    {'a':10, 'b':[7,8,9]},
    {'a':100, 'b':[100,200,300]}
   ], 

   [
     {'a':123, 'b':[9,5,2]},
     {'a':100, 'b':[100,200,300]}
   ], 

   [
    {'a':10, 'b':[7,8,9]}
   ]
]

l = [i for d in results for i in in_list]
```

This will output:

```
[
  {'b': [1, 2, 3], 'a': 1}, 
  {'b': [7, 8, 9], 'a': 10}, 
  {'b': [100, 200, 300], 'a': 100}, 
  {'b': [9, 5, 2], 'a': 123}, 
  {'b': [100, 200, 300], 'a': 100}, 
  {'b': [7, 8, 9], 'a': 10}
]
```

Now to remove duplicates you can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group similar elements. You need to specify group key as both of your elements

```
  from itertools import groupby
  from operator import itergetter

  r = [k for k,g in list(itertools.groupby(sorted([[(k,v) for k,v in d.items()] for d in l]), itemgetter(0,1)))]
```

This will output

```
 [
   (('b', [1, 2, 3]), ('a', 1)), 
   (('b', [7, 8, 9]), ('a', 10)), 
   (('b', [9, 5, 2]), ('a', 123)), 
   (('b', [100, 200, 300]), ('a', 100))
 ]
```

Finally cast this sequence to dict to get your desired output

```
 [dict(e) for e in r]
```

This will output

```
 [
  {'b': [1, 2, 3], 'a': 1}, 
  {'b': [7, 8, 9], 'a': 10}, 
  {'b': [9, 5, 2], 'a': 123}, 
  {'b': [100, 200, 300], 'a': 100}
 ]
```